# display merged posts from multisite and sort by latest date

Tags: multisite

i have a code. it works, but not perfectly: every site have the category "noticias" but don't display posts together ordered by latest date, only as a sequence (blog 1: 3 post order by date, blog 2: 3 post order by date, blog 3: 3 post order by date, etc.) and i want to display all together.

the site: the yellow are from blogs 2-3

[image]

the code

```
$blog_ids = array( 1, 2, 3, );
foreach( $blog_ids as $id ) {
switch_to_blog( $id );
$args = array(
'category_name' => 'noticias',
'post_status' => 'publish',
'orderby' => 'publish_date',
'order' => 'DESC',
'posts_per_page' => '4',
);

$query = new WP_Query( $args );

if( $query->have_posts() ) :
while( $query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post() ; 
?>

<div class="col-md-3 mb-36">
<div class="uc-card card-height--same">

<span class="tag-fixed"><?php $tags = get_the_tags($post->ID);  ?>
            <?php foreach($tags as $tag) :  ?><a class="uc-tag" href="<?php bloginfo('url');?>/tag/<?php print_r($tag->slug);?>"><?php print_r($tag->name); ?></a> <?php endforeach; ?></span>
<div class="uc-card_body">
  <p class="p-size--sm p-color--gray p-text--condensed"><?php //the_date();?></p>
  <h4><?php the_title(); ?></h4>
  <div class="uc-text-divider divider-primary my-20"></div>
  <div class="mt-auto">
    <a href=" <?php echo get_permalink(); ?> " class="uc-btn btn-inline">
      Ver más
      <i class="uc-icon">keyboard_arrow_right</i>
    </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<?php
endwhile;
endif;
wp_reset_postdata();
restore_current_blog();}
```

I hope you can help me,
greetings!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get posts from sites in Multisite?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/98965/get-posts-from-sites-in-multisite)

Comment: nope. its the same issue, i want to see a mixed posts from different blogs ordered by date

Answer (score 0):

**The solution (with template parts):**

```
$blogs = array( 1,4,5 );
$all_posts = array();
foreach( $blogs as $blog ) {
    switch_to_blog( $blog );
    $args = array( 'category_name' => 'noticias', 'posts_per_page' => 2, 'orderby' => 'publish_date', 'order' => 'DESC');
    $blog_posts = get_posts( $args );
    foreach( $blog_posts as $blog_post ) {
        // Correct permalink, blogname, blog url and post thumnail (with size)
        $blog_post->permalink = get_the_permalink( $blog_post->ID );
        $blog_post->blogname = get_bloginfo( $blog_post->ID, 'name'  );
        $blog_post->blogurl = get_site_url($blog_post->ID);
        $blog_post->post_thumbnail_url = get_the_post_thumbnail_url($blog_post->ID, 'noticia-archivo'); 
        $all_posts[] = $blog_post;
    }
    restore_current_blog();
}

usort( $all_posts, '__sort_by_date' );
// Display all posts
foreach( $all_posts as $post ) {
setup_postdata( $post );
// Template part
get_template_part( 'template-parts/card-1' );       
}

function __sort_by_date( $b, $a ) {
    $a_date = strtotime( $a->post_date );
    $b_date = strtotime( $b->post_date );
    if( $a_date === $b_date ) { return 0; }
    if( $a_date > $b_date ) { return 1; }
    return -1;
}
```

**the template part:**

```
<div class="item">
<div class="card-height--same">
<img src= <?php echo '"'.esc_url($post->post_thumbnail_url).'"'; ?> class="img-fluid" alt="">
<span class="tag-fixed"><a href="<?php echo( '' . $post->permalink . '' ); ?>" style="background: #fec60d;color: #444;"> <?php echo $post->blogname; ?> </a></span>
        <div class="uc-card_body">
          <p class="p-size--sm p-color--gray p-text--condensed"><?php the_date();?></p>
          <h4><?php the_title(); ?></h4>
          <div class="mt-auto">
<?php echo( '<a class="uc-btn btn-inline" href="' . $post->permalink . '">' ); echo( 'Ver más<i class="uc-icon">keyboard_arrow_right</i></a>' ); ?>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```